# Linux Gonme: Start multiple terminals and execute a command in each one

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

How can I implement the following scenario in Ubuntu Linux?

I want to go to my console, then execute `./startdev.sh` and then

1) Terminal 1 pops up, starts `/home/foobar/bla1.sh`
2) Terminal 2 pops up, starts `/home/foobar/bla2.sh`
3) Terminal 3 pops up, starts `/home/foobar/bla3.sh`

I already figured that the command "`gnome-terminal` & `disown`" starts a new terminal.
However, until now, I don't know how to run a command in that terminal.

I accept any answer that gives me either the entire implementation for `startdev.sh` or a list of commands that I can use.

Thank you!

Comment: When you launch gnome-terminal, you can use the option `-e` or `--command=STRING` to execute the argument to this option inside the terminal, or with the option `-x` or `--execute` to execute the remainder of the command line inside the terminal.

Comment: Check this thread. --> https://askubuntu.com/questions/484993/run-command-on-anothernew-terminal-window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this content for **startdev.sh**:

```
#!/bin/bash

gnome-terminal --command=/home/foobar/bla1.sh & disown
gnome-terminal --command=/home/foobar/bla2.sh & disown
gnome-terminal --command=/home/foobar/bla3.sh & disown
```

But it is not clear for me why you need to disown the launched processes.

Comment: thank you! i start 3 web servers in debug-mode. i just need the output.

Answer (score 1):

Try this script

If you need to simultaneously pop all terminals

```
#!/bin/bash
gnome-terminal -e "bash -c '/home/foobar/bla1.sh; sleep 10'" | gnome-terminal -e "bash -c '/home/foobar/bla2.sh; sleep 10'" | gnome-terminal -e "bash -c '/home/foobar/bla3.sh; sleep 10'"
```

else if you need to run commands one by one terminal then .,

```
#!/bin/bash
gnome-terminal -e "bash -c '/home/foobar/bla1.sh; sleep 10'" 
gnome-terminal -e "bash -c '/home/foobar/bla2.sh; sleep 10'" 
gnome-terminal -e "bash -c '/home/foobar/bla3.sh; sleep 10'"
```

this script will open multiple terminals and execute the command given within the quotes and i have used sleep to hold the terminal from exiting if not added gnome-terminal will execute command and exit immediately.